# Anti-aliasing for Chrome and Opera

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, opera, font-smoothing

I've seen theories around the interwebs for solutions to the cleartype issues with Chrome, Opera, and IE7-8. IE9 and Firefox ignore a user's preferences for cleartype, so I was wondering if there was a way to force a website's fonts to display as anti-aliased for each user visiting? I've tried hidden text-shadow, -webkit-font-smoothing, a little extra text-stroke, and more, all to no avail. Help?

Comment: Can we see these tests? And what font(s) are you working with?

Comment: Well, the tests didn't actually do anything at all. I want to get either Univers or Helvetica Neue working, and at this point it doesn't really matter which one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't force browsers to render text with anti-aliasing, especially if they've chosen to respect the user's preference to not anti-alias text.